# How do you get a payload from a previous run in the azure logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to test a cloned logic app with an example payload. The logic app waits for HTTP requests. I want the payload that is sent to the HTTP request. How do I get the payload from a previous run?

Answer (score 0):

You dont really have to do much while retrieving the payload. You just need to use `Body` of your HTTP Request. Consider, Below is the flow in logic app.

[image]

Below is a sample payload I using while sending the request.

```
{
    "a":"a",
    "b":"b",
    "c":"c"
}
```

**RESULTS:**

[image]

Codeview of my logic app

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@triggerBody()",
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```